# Iterate 45 times over a numpy.ndarray of shape (45, 2040, 5200,3) can't concatenate int to tuple

Tags: python, image, numpy, tuples, pixel

I'm trying to iterate 45 images data, which is of shape (2040,5200) and 3 color channels. The numpy array data has shape (45,2040,5200,3). I'm trying to get the (2040,5200) values of all 45 images as np.zeros

```
marker_image=[]
i=0

for i in enumerate(data):
    imm = np.zeros(data[i].shape[:2],dtype=np.uint8)
    #marker_image.npbytes
    marker_image.append(imm)
    i+1
```

getting this error 'can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple'

How do I get this resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are sticking with is not related to `numpy` or `list` or anything but just the way you are using `enumerate`. This function, which takes an iterable value, such as `list`, `numpy` array and variables like them, gives you a tuple. The first element of the tuple is the index of the value and the second value is the element in the iterable variable. So, `i` is a tuple, and you are trying to call `i += 1` on a tuple which is not acceptable. `enumerate` is usually being used in this way:

```py
marker_image=[]
i=0

for index, value in enumerate(data):
    imm = np.zeros(data[i].shape[:2],dtype=np.uint8)
    #marker_image.npbytes
    marker_image.append(imm)
    # What you want to do in the rest code
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Amir! but then i got it!